# Pendant Light is Hanging Crooked- How to align it with three screw mount?

Tags: lighting

I have a pendant light that was installed before I moved into this home. The pendant cover is held in place by three screws, in a triangle. I recently replaced the lights, but cannot figure out how to get the cover to sit nicely and perpendicular to the floor, particularly given that I have to hold the cover while screwing in the screws.

A picture is attached showing two of the three shoes and the crookedness.

Apologies if this is easy, but I can't figure out the right search terms for it.[image: Picture of light]

Comment: I think it would be easy as just moving the chain to the notch on the ring to the left.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly loosen the screws that are too high then tighten the ones that are too low.

This will move the weight of the bowl to the high side, rebalancing it.

Repeat until satisfied.

Comment: If the globe is somewhat off kilter due to manufacturing method, loosening the screws and rotating it may also make a difference in how it hangs. If it's perfectly uniform that should not change anything.